# В чём разница между "выучиться" и "научиться"?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов, синонимы

В чём разница между этими глаголами? Они cинонимы или нет? Приведите примеры, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эти слова близки по значению, но, как правило, не синонимы.

Выучиться — обрести профессию (не обязательно окончив учебное заведение). Чаще всего этот глагол употребляют применительно к рабочим профессиям и ремёслам:

"пошёл учеником на завод и выучился на токаря",

"пошёл на курсы и выучился на ветеринара".

В принципе, не будет ошибкой применить это слово и к ВУЗовскому образованию ("выучился на врача"). Однако такое словоупотребление встречается реже.

Научиться — обрести навык. Например, научиться плавать брассом, научиться варить щи, научиться свистеть, научиться держать язык за зубами, научиться хорошим манерам.

В отдельных ситуациях "выучиться" и "научиться" могут быть и синонимами. Это те редкие случаи, когда обретение отдельного навыка оказывается эквивалентно освоению ремесла. Скажем, "научиться вышивать" = "выучиться вышиванию".